# PyQt - Overlaying two widgets without affecting interaction UI-User

Tags: python, pyqt, rangeslider

I am currently making some experiments applying the following [RangeSlider](https://github.com/rsgalloway/QRangeSlider) (done by another user) in a bigger program. Right now, is used to choose a time interval. I wanted to adapt the code, in order to see a vertical line in the point I am interested to. Here there are some examples I did with an image editor.

What I have:

[image: Before]

What I would like:

[image: Goal]

In my current code, when I add a line by using `QLine` and `QPainter.drawLine`, I get the line, but it does not behave in the way that I want. For example, when I move the green range, the line also moves along with it (it should be static). It also create problems with the user-interaction, because if, for example, the line is just above the grey part of the range, then I am not able to select it with the mouse pointer (it´s like if the line overlays, and disable the interaction of the range)

After doing some attempts, I am not able to create something like that above the range.

This is my code (I adapted to not show any lines on it).

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import uic

from PyQt4.QtGui import QGridLayout, QSplitter, QGroupBox, QApplication, HBoxLayout, QWidget, QPainter, QColor, QFont

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

__all__ = ['QRangeSlider']

DEFAULT_CSS = """
QRangeSlider * {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
QRangeSlider #Head {
    background: #a7adba;
}
QRangeSlider #Span {
    background: #343d46;
}
QRangeSlider #Span:active {
    background: #343d46;
}
QRangeSlider #Tail {
    background: #a7adba;
}
QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle {
    background: #4f5b66;
}
QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle:vertical {
    height: 4px;
}
QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle:pressed {
    background: #ca5;
}
"""


def scale(val, src, dst):
    """
    Scale the given value from the scale of src to the scale of dst.
    """
    return int(((val - src[0]) / float(src[1]-src[0])) * (dst[1]-dst[0]) + dst[0])


class Ui_Form(object):
    """default range slider form"""

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("QRangeSlider"))
        Form.resize(300, 30)
        Form.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8(DEFAULT_CSS))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self._splitter = QSplitter(Form)
        self._splitter.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self._splitter.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self._splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self._splitter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("splitter"))
        self._head = QGroupBox(self._splitter)
        self._head.setTitle(_fromUtf8(""))
        self._head.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Head"))
        self._handle = QGroupBox(self._splitter)
        self._handle.setTitle(_fromUtf8(""))
        self._handle.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Span"))
        self._tail = QGroupBox(self._splitter)
        self._tail.setTitle(_fromUtf8(""))
        self._tail.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Tail"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self._splitter, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


class Element(QGroupBox):

    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Element, self).__init__(parent)
        self.main = main

    def setStyleSheet(self, style):
        """redirect style to parent groupbox"""
        self.parent().setStyleSheet(style)

    def textColor(self):
        """text paint color"""
        return getattr(self, '__textColor', QColor(125, 125, 125))

    def setTextColor(self, color):
        """set the text paint color"""
        if type(color) == tuple and len(color) == 3:
            color = QColor(color[0], color[1], color[2])
        elif type(color) == int:
            color = QColor(color, color, color)
        setattr(self, '__textColor', color)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """overrides paint event to handle text"""
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        if self.main.drawValues():
            self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()


class Head(Element):
    """area before the handle"""

    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Head, self).__init__(parent, main)

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        # Adding a line
        qp.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.drawLine(25, 0, 25, 50)

        qp.setPen(self.textColor())
        qp.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, str(self.main.min()))


class Tail(Element):
    """area after the handle"""

    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Tail, self).__init__(parent, main)

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        # Adding a line
        qp.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.drawLine(50, 0, 50, 50)

        qp.setPen(self.textColor())
        qp.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignRight, str(self.main.max()))


class Handle(Element):
    """handle area"""

    def __init__(self, parent, main):
        super(Handle, self).__init__(parent, main)

    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        # Adding a line
        qp.setPen(QColor(255, 0, 0))
        qp.drawLine(75, 0, 75, 50)

        qp.setPen(self.textColor())
        qp.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, str(self.main.start()))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignRight, str(self.main.end()))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        mx = event.globalX()
        _mx = getattr(self, '__mx', None)
        vrange = self.main.max() - self.main.min()
        size = self.main.width()
        step = vrange/size
        if not _mx:
            setattr(self, '__mx', mx)
            dx = 0
        else:
            dx = mx - _mx
        dx *= step
        if -1 < dx < 1:
            event.ignore()
            return
        dx = round(dx)
        setattr(self, '__mx', mx)

        s = self.main.start() + dx
        e = self.main.end() + dx
        if s >= self.main.min() and e <= self.main.max():
            self.main.setRange(s, e)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        setattr(self, '__mx', event.globalX())


class QRangeSlider(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    """
    The QRangeSlider class implements a horizontal range slider widget.
    Inherits QWidget.
    Methods
        * __init__ (self, QWidget parent = None)
        * bool drawValues (self)
        * int end (self)
        * (int, int) getRange (self)
        * int max (self)
        * int min (self)
        * int start (self)
        * setBackgroundStyle (self, QString styleSheet)
        * setDrawValues (self, bool draw)
        * setEnd (self, int end)
        * setStart (self, int start)
        * setRange (self, int start, int end)
        * setSpanStyle (self, QString styleSheet)
    Signals
        * endValueChanged (int)
        * maxValueChanged (int)
        * minValueChanged (int)
        * startValueChanged (int)
    Customizing QRangeSlider
    You can style the range slider as below:
    ::
        QRangeSlider * {
            border: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        QRangeSlider #Head {
            background: #222;
        }
        QRangeSlider #Span {
            background: #393;
        }
        QRangeSlider #Span:active {
            background: #282;
        }
        QRangeSlider #Tail {
            background: #222;
        }
    Styling the range slider handles follows QSplitter options:
    ::
        QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle {
            background: #393;
        }
        QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle:vertical {
            height: 4px;
        }
        QRangeSlider > QSplitter::handle:pressed {
            background: #ca5;
        }

    """
    endValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    maxValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    minValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    startValueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    # define splitter indices
    _SPLIT_START = 1
    _SPLIT_END = 2

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Create a new QRangeSlider instance.

            :param parent: QWidget parent
            :return: New QRangeSlider instance.

        """
        super(QRangeSlider, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setMouseTracking(False)

        self._splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self._handleMoveSplitter)

        # head layout
        self._head_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self._head_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self._head_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._head.setLayout(self._head_layout)
        self.head = Head(self._head, main=self)
        self._head_layout.addWidget(self.head)

        # handle layout
        self._handle_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self._handle_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self._handle_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._handle.setLayout(self._handle_layout)
        self.handle = Handle(self._handle, main=self)
        self.handle.setTextColor((150, 255, 150))
        self._handle_layout.addWidget(self.handle)

        # tail layout
        self._tail_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self._tail_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self._tail_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self._tail.setLayout(self._tail_layout)
        self.tail = Tail(self._tail, main=self)
        self._tail_layout.addWidget(self.tail)

        # defaults
        self.setMin(0)
        self.setMax(99)
        self.setStart(0)
        self.setEnd(99)
        self.setDrawValues(True)

    def min(self):
        """:return: minimum value"""
        return getattr(self, '__min', None)

    def max(self):
        """:return: maximum value"""
        return getattr(self, '__max', None)

    def setMin(self, value):
        """sets minimum value"""
        value = float(value)
        assert type(value) is float
        setattr(self, '__min', value)
        self.minValueChanged.emit(value)

    def setMax(self, value):
        """sets maximum value"""
        value = float(value)
        assert type(value) is float
        setattr(self, '__max', value)
        self.maxValueChanged.emit(value)

    def start(self):
        """:return: range slider start value"""
        return getattr(self, '__start', None)

    def end(self):
        """:return: range slider end value"""
        return getattr(self, '__end', None)

    def _setStart(self, value):
        """stores the start value only"""
        setattr(self, '__start', value)
        self.startValueChanged.emit(value)

    def setStart(self, value):
        """sets the range slider start value"""
        value = float(value)
        assert type(value) is float
        v = self._valueToPos(value)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.disconnect()
        self._splitter.moveSplitter(v, self._SPLIT_START)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self._handleMoveSplitter)
        self._setStart(value)

    def _setEnd(self, value):
        """stores the end value only"""
        setattr(self, '__end', value)
        self.endValueChanged.emit(value)

    def setEnd(self, value):
        """set the range slider end value"""
        value = float(value)
        assert type(value) is float
        v = self._valueToPos(value)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.disconnect()
        self._splitter.moveSplitter(v, self._SPLIT_END)
        self._splitter.splitterMoved.connect(self._handleMoveSplitter)
        self._setEnd(value)

    def drawValues(self):
        """:return: True if slider values will be drawn"""
        return getattr(self, '__drawValues', None)

    def setDrawValues(self, draw):
        """sets draw values boolean to draw slider values"""
        assert type(draw) is bool
        setattr(self, '__drawValues', draw)

    def getRange(self):
        """:return: the start and end values as a tuple"""
        return (self.start(), self.end())

    def setRange(self, start, end):
        """set the start and end values"""
        self.setStart(start)
        self.setEnd(end)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        """overrides key press event to move range left and right"""
        key = event.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            s = self.start()-1
            e = self.end()-1
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            s = self.start()+1
            e = self.end()+1
        else:
            event.ignore()
            return
        event.accept()
        if s >= self.min() and e <= self.max():
            self.setRange(s, e)

    def setBackgroundStyle(self, style):
        """sets background style"""
        self._tail.setStyleSheet(style)
        self._head.setStyleSheet(style)

    def setSpanStyle(self, style):
        """sets range span handle style"""
        self._handle.setStyleSheet(style)

    def _valueToPos(self, value):
        """converts slider value to local pixel x coord"""
        return scale(value, (self.min(), self.max()), (0, self.width()))

    def _posToValue(self, xpos):
        """converts local pixel x coord to slider value"""
        return scale(xpos, (0, self.width()), (self.min(), self.max()))

    def _handleMoveSplitter(self, xpos, index):
        """private method for handling moving splitter handles"""
        hw = self._splitter.handleWidth()

        def _lockWidth(widget):
            width = widget.size().width()
            widget.setMinimumWidth(width)
            widget.setMaximumWidth(width)

        def _unlockWidth(widget):
            widget.setMinimumWidth(0)
            widget.setMaximumWidth(16777215)

        v = self._posToValue(xpos)

        if index == self._SPLIT_START:
            _lockWidth(self._tail)
            if v >= self.end():
                return

            offset = -20
            w = xpos + offset
            self._setStart(v)

        elif index == self._SPLIT_END:
            _lockWidth(self._head)
            if v <= self.start():
                return

            offset = -40
            w = self.width() - xpos + offset
            self._setEnd(v)

        _unlockWidth(self._tail)
        _unlockWidth(self._head)
        _unlockWidth(self._handle)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


rs1 = QRangeSlider()
rs1.show()
rs1.setRange(15, 35)
rs1.setBackgroundStyle('background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1,     stop:0 #222, stop:1 #333);')
rs1.setSpanStyle('background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #282, stop:1 #393);')

app.exec_()
```

**Edit**: I modified the code to show 3 lines and the different effects when I move the range.

I guess the problem comes when I create the line in the same widget, so I should do a separate one for the lines. Am I right?

Comment: One question, the position of the lines as they are determined ?, I ask you because I am seeing 2 possibilities: the first is to try to use your QRangeSlider, but in a certain way it is complicated to implement it, although we should not lose hope, since the other option that I'm thinking about is to create a new QRangeSlider from scratch. :)

Comment: I think I can adapt an implementation of the following widget to what QRangeSlider does https://imgur.com/a/HJ1JwLK